# How can I setup up Ethereum Wallet to launch geth with flags for ethminer?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, ethminer

I see that Ethereum Wallet uses its own `geth.exe` binary which it looks for in `%AppData%\Roaming\Ethereum Wallet\binaries\Geth\unpacked`, on Windows.

It seems this is only one of the processes that are launched when starting the wallet. Is there anyway to tell the wallet to add some flags such as `--rpc --rpccorsdomain localhost`?

Or am I supposed to start **geth** before starting the wallet or starting **ethminer**?